# Getting the Header Rows Count of Multi Column Header in WebDataGrid, Infragistics

Tags: c#, recursion, infragistics

I'm using multi header columns (GroupFields) in WebDataGrid for my project. Is there a way to get the depth of header rows, i.e.. header row count. Consider the depth more than two, i.e.. a sub field can also be a groupfield and contain multiple child fields. So is there a way to compute the total header row count dynamically. I tried recursion, but got stuck since the loop won't stop after recursive fn and continue with the old count. Here is my code, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
protected void MultiColheader(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<GridField> unhiddenColumns = (from GridField p in LookupGrid.Columns
                                           where !p.Hidden
                                           select p).ToList<GridField>();

        int count = 0;
        int[] ar = new int[unhiddenColumns.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < unhiddenColumns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (LookupGrid.Columns[i].GetType() == typeof(GroupField))
            {
                count = 1;
                GroupField groupfield = (GroupField)LookupGrid.Columns[i];
                ar[i] = _HrowCount(groupfield, count);
            }
            count = 0;
        }

        Response.Write(ar.Max());
    }

   public int _HrowCount(GroupField gf, int count)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < gf.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            if (gf.Columns[k].GetType() == typeof(GroupField))
            {
                GroupField gpf = (GroupField)gf.Columns[k];
                count = count + 1;
                _HrowCount(gpf, count);
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function similar to:

```
private int RecursiveIteration(GridFieldCollection field)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < field.Count ; i++)
    {
        if (field[i].GetType() == typeof(GroupField))
        {
            count += RecursiveIteration((field[i] as GroupField).Columns);
        }
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

The function takes a column collection as the argument, so in order to get the total column count:

```
int colCount = RecursiveIteration(WebDataGrid1.Columns);
```

Comment: I did it by passing the count as a reference variable and it works. Thanks anyway.